# How do I replace multiple words in the column of a data frame, with a single word?

Tags: r, gsub, substitution, stringr

I am trying to clean up a database, where factors have been imputed with different words but meaning the same things.

Ex: From *"Purring cat with tail, 4 legs and fur"* or *"European tabby cat"* or *"Cat CAT cat"* to **"Cat"**.

I have looked into `gsub` type of commands and `stringr` commands but wasn't able to achieve my goal.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
Sorry for being unclear, this is my first post.

I would like to replace several words with only one. If "cat" appear anywhere in entry, I want the entire entry to be renamed "Cat". So far I have only been able to replace some part of the entry with something else, but not remove the extra words.

Comment: What exactly is the rule for collapsing here? Are you expecting a computer to know that a "European tabby cat" is the same as a "cat"? What about "adorable feline"? Or are you just looking if "cat" appears anywhere in the phrase, and, if so, replace the entire phrase with "cat"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
x <- c("Purring cat with tail, 4 legs and fur", "European tabby cat", 
"dog", "Cat CAT cat", "bird")

replace(x, grepl("(?i)cat", x, perl=TRUE), "Cat")
# [1] "Cat"  "Cat"  "dog"  "Cat"  "bird"
```